# Gulp error for Polymer Start Kit on OSX

Tags: macos, polymer

Downloaded Polymer starter kit 1.3.0 on 
MAC OSX El Capitan 10.11.4

Node.js V6.0.0

Followed direction here: https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit#getting-started

gulp command gives following error. Help please!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a bug in `gulp-if` (which [pipes *.js to `gulp-uglify`](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/gulpfile.js#L82)) when running under Node v6.0.0. The log error shows that `gulp-uglify` is choking on `app/styles/main.css`, which is odd since it's only supposed to be given *.js.

```
{ Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2026:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2034:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2040:9)
    at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2060:56)
    at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2240:73)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2113:19)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2073:24)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2827:23)
  message: '/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/app/styles/main.css: Unexpected token: punc ({)',
  fileName: '/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/app/styles/main.css',
  lineNumber: 10,
  stack: 'Error\n    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1526:18)\n    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:1534:11)\n    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2026:9)\n    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2034:9)\n    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2040:9)\n    at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2060:56)\n    at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2240:73)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2113:19)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2073:24)\n    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Users/tony/Downloads/polymer-starter-kit-1.3.0/node_modules/uglify-js/tools/node.js:22:1), <anonymous>:2827:23)',
  showStack: false,
  showProperties: true,
  plugin: 'gulp-uglify' }
```

A workaround is to downgrade Node to 5.11.0 (e.g., `$ brew switch node 5.11.0`).

**UPDATE:** I tracked the issue down to [`gulp-match`](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-match/blob/master/index.js#L18-26), which is used by `gulp-if` to check whether the given filename matches a pattern.

You can use this workaround with Node 6.0.0 or earlier versions:

1. In Polymer Starter Kit's `gulpfile.js`, add the following:

   ```
   var filter = function(pattern) {
     return function(file) {
       if (typeof pattern === 'string') {
         var newCond = pattern.substring(1).replace(/\./g,'\\.')+'$';
         pattern = new RegExp(newCond);
       }
       return pattern.test(file.relative);
     };
   };

   var _if = function(pattern, trueChild, falseChild, minimatchOptions) {
     return $.if(filter(pattern), trueChild, falseChild, minimatchOptions);
   };
   ```
2. In `optimizeHtmlTask()`, replace `$.if` with `_if`.

---

<sup>See Polymer Issue [#880](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/issues/808), gulp-match issue [#12](https://github.com/robrich/gulp-match/issues/12)</sup>